# For a project, search issues whose title includes ".*.", or strictly "operator", or through a regular expression

Tags: gitlab

I used to use Bugzilla and its very powerful search engine.

But the project and its bug tracker have been moved to Gitlab.

1. When trying to search (in online Gitlab), for the project, all issues whose title includes some item like `"./"`, or `".*."` (Kronecker product), or `"//"` (1-line comments), etc, no issue is returned, while many issues matching the query actually exist! I tried with `"\.\*\."` and other trials, with no more success.

   What should be the query syntax to return the right list?
2. When querying `"operator"` (with the double quotes for exact matching), when validating the query, quotes disappear, and i get a list of issues whose title includes *operand*, or *operation*, or *oper*, etc. How can i get only issues exactly matching `"operator"` ?
3. Is is possible to filter issues with a title matching a regular expression?

All this (and much more) was possible and very useful with Bugzilla. And for the time being, i am quite handicapped and loose a lot of time when Searching things for the project on Gitlab.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

The features of GitLab's basic search are quite limited for Issues, particularly regarding fuzzy searches.

[Advanced search](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search.html) is included in paid subscriptions only. Based on [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/), it offers tools for fuzzy (`~` fuzzy, `*` partial) and exact (`"`) search, as well as logical operators (`+` and, `|` or, `-` exclude).

According to the [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html), regular expression queries should be possible, too. But since I came here facing the exact same obstacles with our free GitLab instance and the GitLab docs don't provide further info on the topic, I wasn't able to check if/how it works.